# Enforce overriding exactly one of two methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, overriding, abstract-class, option-type

I have a type of object, call it `AbstractFoo`, which can "accept" or "reject" instances of a particular class `Bar` based on the properties of that instance. Therefore, I add the following method in the `AbstractFoo` base class:

```
public abstract boolean acceptsBar(Bar bar);
```

However, I then find that in certain cases I need to know *why* `Bar` was rejected, and this rejection message is complicated enough to warrant a new type of object to represent it: `BarRejection`. Then I add the following method to the `AbstractFoo` base class:

```
public abstract Optional<BarRejection> getBarRejection(Bar bar);
```

If `Bar` was rejected, this method returns the reason; otherwise it returns `Optional.empty()`. Of course, now the result of this method completely determines whether `acceptsBar` should be true, so I update that method:

```
public final boolean acceptsBar(Bar bar) {
    return !getBarRejection(bar).isPresent();
}
```

This is all well and good, except now I'm left with what I consider a style problem. In the majority of cases, I don't care why `Bar` was rejected, so I end up writing something like the following:

```
@Override
public Optional<BarRejection> getBarRejection(Bar bar) {
    return ([acceptance condition]) ? Optional.empty() : BarRejection.default();
}
```

Here, the `Optional<BarRejection>` is effectively just a stand-in for a boolean. In these cases, it would be much more preferable to allow classes to implement `acceptsBar` and push the `getBarRejection` code up to the superclass:

```
public final Optional<BarRejection> getBarRejection(Bar bar) {
    return acceptsBar(bar) ? Optional.empty() : BarRejection.default();
}
```

It would really be ideal to force the derived classes of `AbstractFoo` to implement *exactly one* of the two methods, with the unimplemented method taking on its default behavior. Obviously this isn't possible to do directly in Java, but is there a design pattern that would allow me to accomplish something similar?

Comment: `default` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Since you now have real world use cases, can you list three when you handle the rejection? What's the typical action? Logging something? Throwing an exception?

Comment: I've had a similar scenario where 3 default methods forwarded their implementation to one another, and I left a warning in the documentation that one of the methods must be overridden. Not the ideal solution, but I couldn't find a better one.

Comment: @shmosel In my understanding, `default` works specifically for interfaces, in which case it is the same as implementing a method in an abstract class as I've done in the question (maybe I should have been more clear about the nature of `Foo`). Aside from allowing both methods to be overridden, the issue I see with implementing both `default`s in an interface is that they refer to one another, and the compiler will not warn the user about this behavior. Implementing the interface without overriding at least one would lead to a stack overflow (if doing so is even legal at compile time).

Comment: That's right. I decided to take that risk. Not ideal, like I said.

Comment: @shmosel Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @Raffaele The resulting action is to pop a notification (or sometimes no notification at all, which is the default behavior). The `BarRejection` carries the particular notification instance, which typically needs to be constructed in the context that `Bar` is rejected because it includes information descriptive of that context.

Comment: And what is the number of use cases? I mean, how many usages of the API are there vs how many implementations of the API? How do you expect them to grow? I ask this because your question is a style advice so things will work anyhow but the code will look different so your choice will take into account readability, debuggability, testability, ease of deployment and so on. If you want an informed advice I think your best bet is rewriting the question with the actual types and use-cases

Comment: @Raffaele Since I'm working on a commercial closed-source project on behalf of a company, I hesitate to post too much about the specific details of the problem. But I take your point about the answer depending on the use cases. I guess I was hoping for a solution to the general problem I posed in the title (a la the Visitor pattern as a solution for the problem of safely implementing double dispatch in statically typed languages). But I understand that such a solution may not exist.

Comment: Exactly! In the end you may even find that a simple `void foo() throws Exception` is the best tradeoff

Answer (score 2):

You can make a second abstract base class for clients who do not want to provide a rejection reason:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    public final boolean acceptsBar(Bar bar) {
        return !getBarRejection(bar).isPresent();
    }
    public abstract Optional<BarRejection> getBarRejection(Bar bar);
}

public abstract class AbstractQuickRejectFoo extends AbstractFoo {
    @Override
    public Optional<BarRejection> getBarRejection(Bar bar) {
        return checkAcceptBar(bar) ? Optional.empty() : BarRejection.getDefault();
    }
    protected abstract boolean checkAcceptBar(Bar bar);
}
```

Derived classes that want to provide a custom reason would inherit `AbstractFoo` directly, while classes that want to provide a default reason would inherit `AbstractQuickRejectFoo`. Each class offers a single abstract method for their subclasses to override.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, you are right, I renamed the class, but forgot to rename the reference.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I had hoped not to further complicate the class hierarchy simply to accommodate this one singular construct, but I think I understood intuitively that it might be the only real "object-oriented" way to handle the situation. The main issue here is that there are a number of extensible `Foo` subclasses whose specific behavior is orthogonal to whether they should `QuickReject` or not, so each of these would require its own `QuickReject` equivalent. I think the current system is probably preferable to doing this. But, +1.